# How the database connection is built in the deployment

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, deployment, installation

I'm new to development in .NET and now I've just finished developing a solution. Its a C# standalone windows application and for data base access its using ADO.NET and RDBMS is SQL Server 2008.

I need to create an installer and so I created a msi using the IDE.

Using this msi, I would setup the application in another PC after installing .net framework and SQL Server on it as prerequisites. Then I would run a database script file or restore a database backup manually.  Then when I run the msi I wish to install my application.

I wonder how the database connection to SQL server would be established in this way in the new setup. Does the msi contain that information? (In the project I've used a app.config file to store the connection string)

Comment: Even your restore script is going to need to find the database.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication.enumavailablesqlservers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simply you could use the server: localhost\sqlexpress in your connection string of your file app.config, assuming that you will always install sql using default settings (means named instance \sqlexpress), users should be able to connect to the database the same way you do on your local development machine.

As you, I am not a msi expert, but if you need a simple way to go forward I think this might help.

Comment: It didn't work for me even I used localhost in con str and default settings when installing :(

Comment: Can you give more details? What is the connection string that is in the app.exe.config file after you have installed the app using the msi?